# Add more info in the attribute table after executing "Line intersection" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, analysis

I have executed the "Line intersection" tool on a road shapefile. This is under `Vector > Analysis Tools > Line intersections`. I get an output with attribute table having just two columns: `type_1` and `type_2`.

Is it possible to get more info/attributes out of this? For example, the `node_ids` of the intersections and perhaps their location (latitude and longitude)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add further info, such as the coordinates of intersection points, editing the attribute table and calculating the coordinates with the field calculator using the geometric functions `$x` and `$y`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I can't seem to find though an option wherein I can add an attribute that labels the (intersection) node using its original ID attribute from OSM data.

Comment: As shown in the example above (self intersection of a line layer), `id_1` and `id_2` are _only_ the IDs of lines which intersect (because the line layer attribute table contains an `id` field), while I imagine that the original node ID is completely different. So you should import the OSM nodes directly, if you are interested in their original IDs.

Comment: Thanks, @afalciano. I have already imported OSM nodes into the workplace; however, it is still not very straightforward to map the latitude and longitude back to the OSM nodes directly. I have written a Python code that tries to match the lat and lon from the intersection shapefile to the lat and lon of the nodes in the OSM data, only less than 10% were matched.

Comment: If `Vector --> Data management tools --> Join attributes by location` doesn't help, I suggest you to ask another question describing your task and attaching your code.